# Lenovo x1carbon 8th gen with debian 9 doesn't recognize touchpad

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I'm struggling for more than one month, fighting to make the touchpad works on x1carbon 8th gen with Debian stretch. Yes stretch, it means the latest kernel I can work on is 4.19 (backports)
The touchpad is not recognized in `/proc/bus/input/devices`
This is the output of the xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                           id=2   [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                         id=12  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                          id=3   [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                               id=6   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                               id=7   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 USB Audio  id=8   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C            id=9   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                           id=10  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=11  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                     id=13  [slave  keyboard (3)]
but the lsusb I can find some information:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc.
```

If I boot using ubuntu live everything is ok with kernel 5.8 and xinput identify this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                  id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer        id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8006:00 06CB:CD8B Mouse       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8006:00 06CB:CD8B Touchpad    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                 id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard       id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                      id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                         id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ sof-hda-dsp Headset Jack          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons            id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have tried everything, kernel parameters, changed between synaptcs and libinput drivers, change re-compile kernel with some i2c parameters. No luck so far. Go to buster or another Linux OS with a new kernel is not an option. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment yet, so I have to write here... this "lovely" website, right? LOL)
I was able to make my Lenovo S145 (launch 2019) touchpad work on Manjaro 20.04 (kernel 5.8) It's an Elan touchpad, right? (these things are crappy as hell, compared to my 10 year old Synaptics touchpad which was just perfect)
Excuse me asking, but why are you using such old distro on a brand new hardware? Why are you stuck with that one?
For these particular models of Elan touchpads, you will have to look for kernel patches from 2019 onwards, I don't know how to install them, I never had to do it myself.
I think this link has some of them?
https://www.x.org/archive//individual/driver/

Latest version of Libinput there is 19-May-2020 and there's a Synaptics file from May-2018 too. Just have to find [how to install them on your system.](https://github.com/mishurov/linux_elan1200_touchpad)

If you ever find how to tune up movement speed on these touchpads, let me know, I'm not finding any options to fine-tune it like Synaptics had.